# Python: Split a string into different elements after a ,

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to split a string that I searched for into a few subelements to find information. 
My Text has this structure:

```
INPUT_1_NAME=INPUT_1_NAME,INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT=0,INPUT_1_STANDARD=625/25i,INPUT_1_STATE=OK,INPUT_1_TYPE=HD / SD / 3G SDI,INPUT_2_IDENT=2,INPUT_2_NAME=INPUT_2_NAME,INPUT_2_SDI_ERRCNT=0,
```

My Script so far is:

```
with open('Test.rtf') as f:
   for line in f:
        if 'NAME=NEQ1-VIF2601' in line:
```

I searched in the whole Text file for the information of the device NEQ1-VIF2601. Now i want to find the INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT information out of this string for example

Comment: The python doc is your friend, `somestring.split(...)` too.

Comment: I still not get, what you trying. Can u add more information in your question. means Input, respective Output in more details.

Comment: My Input is the Test.rtf It's a generated Text file from a Server. I filtered out the device NAME=NEQ1-VIF2601. Now I want to filter out the INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT=0 information to write it to a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? This will split every line at a comma and split every resulting element to `left` (left side of equal-sign) and `right` (right side of equal -sign)

```
with open('Test.rtf') as f:
      for line in f:
           for element in line.split(","):
               left, right = element.split("=")[0], element.split("=")[1]
```

Comment: I think that's the right way. I'm sorry I started yesterday with Python, because I need it for a project. 
Basically I want to filter out the value of INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT.

Comment: What if there's multiple `=` in the element, e.g. `"a=1=2"`? Your code will simply discard the `=2` part. Do you want an error? Use `left, right = element.split("=")`. Do you want the `=2` part? Use `left, right = element.split("=", maxsplit=1)`.

Comment: You could iterate through the elements till `left == 'INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT'` when the code runs into this if-statement the `right` variable contains your desired information

Comment: Remember to `Accept` the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Note:-** Please make sure that when you any query it should be understandable for others so that you can get solution very easily and quickly.

Solution for this is. You can split the input string on "," then a **new list** you will get and then check if "**INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT** is present inside the new list and the fetch the value from this new list.

Solution:-

```
find_str = 'INPUT_1_SDI_ERRCNT'
for a in l:
    k = a.split('=')
    if k[0] == find_str:
        print(k[1])
```